# Give door open effect the then jump to next page

Tags: css, html

I want to open a door when I click on it and then after animation completion, open the next page

I have tried HTML animation with perspective option. When door opens, it gets too stretched instead of getting opened.

```
<div class="tile">
    <img src="images/door.jpg" />
</div>

div.tile {
  margin:20px;
  background:red;
  -webkit-animation: example 4s ease 0s infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
 from {
   -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(-90deg);
   -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
 }
 to {
   -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
 }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Door image size is 522px * 1000 px. I updated the perspective value to 2000 and it looks better now. Please tell me why it worked better on giving so big value and will this work fine if I implement bootstrap to show 4 doors in one row?

Comment: `-webkit-animation` — Why are you using these properties prefixed? That's for experimental stuff which isn't properly implemented. All the properties you are using now have standard, non-prefixed, well-supported versions.

Comment: Actually I was looking for solutions over google and found this one working

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe :

```
.container{
    perspective: 300px;
}
div.tile {
    width: 100px; /** Otherwise, the width of the div can exceed the width of the window during the animation **/
    margin:20px;
    background:red;
    animation: example 4s ease 0s infinite alternate;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
@keyframes example{
    from {
        transform:  rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:  rotateY(-90deg);
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="tile">
         <!--<img src="images/door.jpg" />-->
         <div style="width:100px;height:150px;background:blue"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

As Quentin said, animation and transform properties are now standard. You can visit https://caniuse.com/ or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions#Formerly_proprietary_properties_that_are_now_standard) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. You have fixed the width of tile to 100px, but I will be using bootstrap so I would like bootstrap to auto adjust the image width. In that case, I cannot fix the tile width. What else can be the solution?

Comment: The perspective value give the distance from the user to the z=0 plane. The smaller its value is, the deeper the perspective is. Check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) documentation for more infos. Also, if your problem have change can you please udpate your post with the new code your using ?